# Unity С# передать пиксель-перфект по сети, на разных разрешениях

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Есть 2д игра с пиксель перфектом - нужно чтобы кубики становились друг на друга грань к грани как тетрис. Как подобное передать по сети, если играют люди с разным разрешением экрана и соотношением сторон? 
Допустим один экран 768х1024, другой 1080х1920, ориентация портретная, соотношение сторон соответственно 3 к 4, и 9 к 16.

Если я ставлю кубик на кубик на устройстве 4х3, то в коде это выглядит как то так

```
cube2.anchoredPosition = cube1.anchoredPosition + 
(cube2.rect.height/2 + cube1.rect.height/2);
```

В результате получаем

```
Vector3 cube2.anchoredPosition
```

И при отправке его по сети на другом устройстве, с соотношением сторон 9 на 16, мы получим уже другое его местоположение. Т.е. между кубиками может возникнуть щель или они наоборот частично перекроют друг друга.

Дополнительно, Canvas, а значит и игровое поле у игрока с большим разрешением экрана, будет больше, и видеть он будет больше чем игрок с небольшим разрешением. Значит картина будет у них отличатся. Как сделать чтобы этого не происходило? Как настроить канвас и позиции, какие данные передавать, чтобы картина на двух устройствах с разными разрешениями, плотностью пикселей и размером экрана была идентичная?

Comment: Можно попробовать поставить у компонента Canvas scaler такие настройки: Scale with screen size - Expand. Тогда канвас будет всегда умещаться на экране и можно будет работать с одними и теми же координатами - в экранные он преобразует сам.

Comment: @trollingchar
Не совсем понятно как в этом случае задавать точную позицию. Ведь на  экране в 400 пикселей шириной rect.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0,400) будет совсем справа, а на экране в 1920 пикселей - ближе к началу. Как их перевести в эквивалентные единицы?

Comment: Дело в том, что точная позиция будет задаваться уже в масштабированных единицах. То есть на любом экране одинаково. Единственный момент - нужно поставить якоря тех объектов, которые непосредственно дети канваса, на middle-center.

Comment: @trollingchar Т.е. если я при middle-center задам rect.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0,400), он у меня на всех экранах будет выглядеть одинаково?

Comment: А это можно проверить прям в юнити. Надо выбрать вкладку Game, и прямо под словом Game будет либо разрешение, либо соотношение сторон, либо Free Aspect. Щелкаем туда и выбираем разрешение экрана или же ставим свое.

Comment: @trollingchar
Работает, но до определённых пределов. С 1024х768 до 1920х1080 работает ок, а вот 2180х1080 уже не держит, элемент, приближенный вплотную к краю на прошлых разрешениях, становится на полдороги между краем и серединой.

Comment: Это потому что канвас стремится сохранить соотношение сторон, и может либо сверху и снизу пространство появиться, либо по бокам. Я думал, это и нужно было сделать.